Increase accelerometer sensitivity
I have a Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra. I wish to increase the sensitivity of my accelerometer.  I play a combat game with jets and cannot switch to a joystick as I have played too long with an accelerometer, tilting the phones to move left and right.  It is like being able to move quicker left and right.
